# Rails Admin & Mini Profiler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, rack-mini-profiler

I am using rack mini profiler in my Rails application. In addition, I am using Rails Admin as my admin tool.

I am receiving the following message when looking at the dashboard:

> Model 'Mini-profiler-resources' could not be found

Any clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I run into the same problem. My solution was tested with `rails_admin (0.6.1)` and `cancan (1.6.10)`.

`mini-profiler` config contains field called `skip_paths`. The solution is to set this field in the initializer.

1. Edit (create if not exists) `config/initializers/mini_profiler.rb`.
2. Add path you want to ignore. For rails_admin, `/admin` should be ignored:
   `Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_paths ||= []
   Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_paths << '/admin'`

Comment: One suggestion actually. Wrap the config items with: **if defined?(MiniProfiler::Config)**

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.

my workaround is disable `mini-profiler` when visiting `rails_admin`, couple steps

1. change mini_profiler.rb inside initialisers, add

   `Rack::MiniProfiler.config.authorization_mode = :whitelist`
2. change application_controller

   `before_filter :mini_profiler,  unless: :rails_admin_path?`

do not run `mini_profiler` if current request path is '`rails_admin`' path